# Using HTTP GET request to fetch data in an Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular Material table in which I want to fetch data from a service. This is my service.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Message } from '../messages/message-table/message.model';

@Injectable()

export class MessageService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getMessageTableData() {
    return this.http.get<Message[]>('<removed>');
  }
}
```

This is the interface Message for the data

```
export interface Message {
    RequestID: string;
    RequestStatus: string;
    RequestorName: string;
    SubmissionDate: string;
    ApproverName: string;
    ApprovalDate: string;
    Subject: string;
    MessageStatus: string;
    ReadStatus: string;
  }
```

In my component.ts file, I'm able to display the data in console using this,

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.messageService.getMessageTableData().subscribe(
      (response) => console.log(response)
    )
}
```

I've seen the example code on Angular material's website but since I have a lot of client side filtering on my table, I want to use MatTableDataSource for my dataSource. That example uses a custom dataSource and I'm not able to include my filters in that. How can I display this data, which is coming in JSON form from my service, in my table?

Attaching the HTML code for my table as well

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="RequestID">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Request ID </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.RequestID}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="RequestStatus">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Request Status </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.RequestStatus}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="RequestorName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Requestor Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.RequestorName}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="SubmissionDate">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Submission Date </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.SubmissionDate}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="ApproverName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Approver Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ApproverName}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="ApprovalDate">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Approval Date </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ApprovalDate}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Subject">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Subject </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Subject}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="MessageStatus">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Message Status </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.MessageStatus}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="ReadStatus">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Read Status </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ReadStatus}} </td>
    </ng-container>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to create an instance of the `MatTableDataSource` and pass it the data that you're getting from your service. Something like this:

```
import { MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
...

@Component({...})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  dataSource;

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.messageService.getMessageTableData()
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response);
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      });
  }

  ...

}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-modal?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: It is still not showing any data, I can see that the table is getting rendered as there are a lot of rows generated but my page is totally empty as in the rows dont have any data

Answer (score 1):

You can filter this datasource or am i missing something

```
dataSource: any;
ngOnInit() {
   this.messageService.getMessageTableData().subscribe(
     (response) => this.dataSource = response
     )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MatTableDataSource` it will help to filter and sort.

```
dataSource: new MatTableDataSource([]);
ngOnInit() {
   this.messageService.getMessageTableData().subscribe( (data) => {
       this.dataSource.data = data || []
   })
}

applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
   this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
}
```

For Reference added [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-83hctd?file=app/table-overview-example.ts) sample code.