# Displaying a material table in Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I'm pretty new to **Angular** and I'm trying to create a table to better display my data. I'm getting the data from a JSON provided by my server.

Content of `data.component.html`:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Search history</h1>
  <table *ngIf="searches">
    <li *ngFor="let search of searches">
      <p class="searchParams">{{search.searchParams}}</p>
      <p class="searchDate">{{search.searchDate | date: "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"}}</p>
    </li>
  </table>
</div>
```

Content of `data.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-data',
  templateUrl: './data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data.component.scss']
})
export class DataComponent implements OnInit {
  searches: Object;
  constructor(private _http: HttpService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._http.getSearches().subscribe(data => {
      this.searches = data;
      console.log(this.searches);
    });
  }
}
```

What I get is something that looks like a bullet list:

[image]

I'm trying to take [this](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) as example but I don't understand how to implement it. What is my datasource here? What HTML should I write to get such a nice looking table?

Comment: It's what you fetch through your service. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53740101/using-http-get-request-to-fetch-data-in-an-angular-material-table

Comment: Also if you click on the little expand button in the docs, it will take you to slack bitz where you can see the underlying code

Comment: Hi @sinanspd, thanks for you answer. I tried clicking on that button but I get an "Internal Server Error". Does it work to you?

Comment: Yes it does. Try this one? https://stackblitz.com/angular/brrmxggvxngj?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-http-example.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something like the angular material table you should actually use it and follow the docs.
If you don't want to use angular material but instead just want a regular HTML table you should adjust you code like that to use actuale table rows and colums:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Search history</h1>
  <table *ngIf="searches">
    <tr *ngFor="let search of searches">
      <td class="searchParams">{{search.searchParams}}</p>
      <td class="searchDate">{{search.searchDate | date: "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"}}</p>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

You can then style your table via CSS.

For an angular material approach you should first install the package and import it to your module. Then you could use a template like that:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="searches" class="mat-elevation-z8">    
  <!-- searchParams Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="searchParams">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Search parameters </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.searchParams}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- searchDate Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="searchDate">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Date </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.searchDate}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

dont forget to define displayColumns in code behind:

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['searchParams', 'searchDate'];
```

Comment: Didn't exactly answer to what I was asking, but at least improved considerably my view, thanks!

Comment: i added the angular material approach

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work,

`data.component.html`

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Keyword Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="keyword">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Keyword </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.keyword}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Limit Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="limit">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Limit </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.limit}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Date Search Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="dateSearch">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Date Search </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.dateSearch | date: "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</tabl1e>
```

`data.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-data',
  templateUrl: './data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data.component.scss']
})
export class DataComponent implements OnInit {
  searches: Object;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'keyword', 'limit', 'date'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
  constructor(private _http: HttpService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._http.getSearches().subscribe(data => {
      this.searches = data;
      this.dataSource = data.map((v, i) => {
        position: i,
        keyword: v.searchParams.keyword,
        limit: v.searchParams.limit,
        dateSearch: v.searchDate
      });
      console.log(this.searches);
    });
  }
}
```