# Display Data in Angular Material Table

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table

I'm struggling with the Angular mat-table library. I got an app with a Node.js backend and an Angular frontend. The node app provides data from a MySQL database in JSON.

Now I want to display this data in a mat-table. I have logged the data in the console, which allows me to see that the data is actually retrieved but just not displayed.

[image: Data in Console]

However, the HTML table is empty:

[image: empty html]

This is my Angular component:

**component.html**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8 demo-table">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.id}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="pop">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Population</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.population}}</td>
  </ng-container>


  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr
      mat-row
      (click)="clickedRows.add(row)"
      [class.demo-row-is-clicked]="clickedRows.has(row)"
      *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
  ></tr>
</table>
```

**component.ts**

```js
import {Component, OnInit,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { Player } from '../player';
import { PlayerService } from '../player.service';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatSort, SortDirection} from '@angular/material/sort';

/**
 * @title Binding event handlers and properties to the table rows.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-players',
  styleUrls: ['players.component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'players.component.html',
})
export class PlayersComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'pop'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Player>();

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort!: MatSort;

  constructor(private playerService:PlayerService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPlayers();
  }

  getPlayers() {
    this.playerService.getPlayers().subscribe(players => {
      console.log(players);
      this.dataSource.data = players;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    });
  }
  clickedRows = new Set<Player>();
}
```

**player.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Player } from './player';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PlayerService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  rootURL = '/api';
  getPlayers(): Observable<Player[]> {
    return this.http.get<Player[]>(this.rootURL+ '/players');
  }
}
```

Any ideas on this?

EDIT:
Could it have something to do with how the array comes back from the API? In Node.js it is retrieved with sequelize and maybe it is the response?

```js
// Get all Players
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
    Player.findAll().then((players) => {
    // Send all players as response
    res.status(200).json({
      status: true,
      data: players,
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: `displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'pop'];`? shouldn't that be `population`?

Comment: i think its just a string to identify the correct column in the mat-table html definition which is defined as `<ng-container matColumnDef="pop">`

EDIT:
Yes, i updated the code - nothing changed in behaviour.

Comment: datasource binding should be `[dataSource]="dataSource.data"` and `this.dataSource.data = players.data;`(according to the screenshot of response). I didn't understand your paginator and sort. I have used it like this. https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-http

Comment: the paginator and sort in my example are properties from MatTableDataSource class. see https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue

The data returned based on the screenshot and Node.js API is not `Player` array, but it is an object with `status` and `data` properties.

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "data": [...]
}
```

This line expected that HTTP GET to receive `Player` array which is conflict with your data.

```js
this.http.get<Player[]>(this.rootURL+ '/players');
```

Hence, it returns Observable with an empty array and your `<mat-table>` will not show the data.

---

### Solution

Transform the data to `Player` array with `map`  rxjs operator.

```js
import { map } from 'rxjs';

getPlayers(): Observable<Player[]> {
  return this.http
    .get(this.rootURL+ '/players')
    .pipe(map((response: any) => response.data as Player[]));
}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gte1xe?file=src/app/player.service.ts)

Comment: this works, thanks a lot! I already thought of something like this, which is why I have attached the API code in my EDIT part.

Answer (score 0):

Create a instance of MatTableDataSource and assign to data Source.
Try this option

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(players);
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
```

Ref: [Using HTTP GET request to fetch data in an Angular Material Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53740101/using-http-get-request-to-fetch-data-in-an-angular-material-table)

Comment: Same issue.. i replaced my code with the new dataSource instance(`this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(players);`) but its still the same behaviour. array is retrieved but not displayed.